# Submitting road data to Google

Tags: commuter, bikeroutes, resource, maps

I have really enjoyed Google Maps cycling directions but find it lacking a lot where I live. I really want to update the maps with new/better information but I don't know the what, how, or where.

- What data can I submit to update Google Maps cycling data?
- What format does the data need to be in to submit it to Google Maps?
- Where do I submit this data? (i.e. url)
- How is the data submitted?

Comment: Wow!  That is so sweeet!  I didn't know google gave bike directions.  They are not in Canada yet, but really excited the feature is on the way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest way to submit data is to **right-click on the map and choose "Report a problem"**.  This pops up a small form with a marker.  You drag the marker where the problem is, and you pick a category and type something to explain the problem.  In a few days, a human being reads it and (assuming he/she agrees) fixes it.

For instance, Google Maps would send bicycle routes near my house to a road with a killer hill.  There's a reasonable alternate route that adds only about a quarter of a mile, but avoids the killer hill for a much more gentle hill.  So I reported it.

In a few days I got an e-mail that said "Your Google Maps problem report has been reviewed, and you were right! We'll update the map soon and email you when you can see the change."

Sometimes you'll also get an e-mail afterwards that says "Google Maps has been updated to correct the problem you reported. You can see the update here, and if you still see a problem, please tell us more about the issue:  (link)"

And now those same bicycle routes, by default, route along the gentle hill instead of the killer hill.

Comment: Agree, and had similar experience with "Report a problem".  For instance, reported that there's a path along a specific creek and they added that to their maps.  Can sometimes take a long time, though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm looking for a way to do something like record a route and submit that. Do you know of anything like that?

Comment: @Mike - I'm not sure about this, but it's possible that using ridewithgps.com might work as a resource. Basically on that site you can trace out a route and after you've finished editing, you can export the route as a kml file. I would guess that you could then submit the kml to google.

Comment: @wdypdx22 That would be great! Where could I submit that kml file?

Comment: @Mike - I was hypothesizing in my previous comment. I haven't looked yet, but would assume that there must (might) be a link somewhere in google maps that allows for such a submission.

Comment: @Mike - I think in order to accomplish that, you have to figure out why Google Maps is picking the less ideal route and submit suggestions that would make it more likely to pick the good route. Using the cycling overlay helps tell you some of that.

Comment: My kingdom for a way to report route problems like this from the Android app!

Answer (score 8):

[openstreetmap.org](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) is a google map style map built from user supplied data.
You can upload GPS tracks and edit the existing map data to add cycle routes or tracks

Comment: Thanks @Martin! openstreetmap.org is great but not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to submit large amounts of data, you might be able to do it using their [Base Map Partner Program](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/basemap/). I haven't tried this myself. See [my answer to the question "Do I have to simply wait for google maps to add cycling directions to my area? Or can I help?"](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1736/do-i-have-to-simply-wait-for-google-maps-to-add-cycling-directions-to-my-area-or/2606#2606).